# forarray's \ForEach isn't robust

Tags: loops

`\ForEach` and related commands of **forarray** package aren't robust. They can't deal with lists whose separators are active (e.g., active comma). Also any trailing space after the list item is retained throughout processing. For example, with

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\,=13
\gdef\x{ {a} , \if , {b} , \fi }
\endgroup
\ForEachX{,}{\typeout{X\unexpanded\expandafter{\thislevelitem}X}}\x
```

I get

```
\fe@item@check@next ->\fe@getitem@i {a}
\fe@getitem@i #1,->\fe@setitem@i {#1}
#1<-{a} , \if , {b} , \fi
...
{changing \thislevelitem=\relax}
{into \thislevelitem=\long macro:->{a} , \if , {b} , \fi }
```

This means that on first grabbing of list item, `\thislevelitem` is the entire list: `->{a} , \if , {b} , \fi`.

Please how do I solve these problems?

Also, it will be less confusing if the following **forarray** syntax

```
\begin{enumerate}
\ForEach{;}{
  \item This is item No.\ \the\thislevelcount.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \ForEachSublevel{,}{\item \thislevelitem.}
  \end{enumerate}
}{%
  This is a nested item, Another nested item ;
  {This item is, well, nested}, A final item
}
\end{enumerate}
```

is made like this

```
\begin{enumerate}
\ForEach{;}{
  \item This is item No.\ \the\thislevelcount.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \ForEach{,}{\item \thislevelitem.}{<level 2 list>}
  \end{enumerate}
}
{<level 1 list>}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: This seems more a feature request than a real question. `\ForEachX` asks for the delimiter and doesn't do *any* sanitization: it's a simple package that does simple loops.

Comment: This may qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ForEach` doesn't perform any sanitization of its input, which makes it unsuitable for usage in a generic package that may be employed in situations where the delimiter has a different category code (this is a common problem for packages dealing with option lists, as you know well).

The `\ForEachX` version does a one level expansion of its third argument. There are more robust ways to process lists with arbitrary delimiters.